OpenAPI Generator C# client generic-host OAuth2
I'm currently generating a C# Client with OpenAPI Generator (7.8.0) and the generic-host library.
The generated code contains an OAuthToken class and a TokenProvider<TToken>. My API is protected via OAuth2 and therefore the generated client requires a TokenProvier<OAuthToken> which is provided by dependency injection.
However, I need help on registering the correct TokenProvider to the service collection. Has anyone managed to use the TokenProvider for OAuth2 and can share some code on how it is set up?
